# How do I force Facebook to not use a pre-made job title for my work and education?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

I'm trying to update my work and education on Facebook, and my title has multiple words in it. However, it insists on changing it to match a pre-made position title with incorrect capitalization. Is there any way to force it to use a new, correctly capitalized title?

Comment: I have a feeling this could be Sql Server / SQL Server related. If you enter your jobtitle in the correct capitalisation then click into the next field rather than selecting the suggested job, does this help?  Cannot test without adding a new job myself...

Comment: Nope, I had a hunch that might work but it still auto-selects the pre-made title.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was attempting "Associate Editor" but someone had put it in as "Associate editor". I put an extra space between the two words and got the "Create Associate Editor" option at the bottom of the dropdown list. I selected it, and it appears to work. The extra space is either not very noticeable on a profile, or Facebook autocorrected it. Looks good to me!

Answer (score -1):

Adding the extra space between the two words in the title worked for me. FB appears to have auto-removed the extra space but it came out with the correct capitalization.